# Getting the First Value of Assigned to (Lookup )

Tags: data

Would it be possible to capture the First Value of the "Assigned to" field(Task Object; Lookup Field) by creating a formula field in Activity Object named "Sample".

Lets say, the "Assigned to" field , is constantly updated, while the "Sample" field still keeps the first value of  "Assigned to", will that be possible??

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SFSE community!! Answer is `YES. It's possible`. May I know, what you have tried for this and where you're struggling?

Comment: As of the moment , I am still struggling for the formula used for "Sample" field, where its Formula Return type is "Text".

Formula used:
PRIORVALUE(Owner:Queue.QueueName)

The error pops up says that the " PRIORVALUE, may not be used in this type of Formula.

Comment: @Mohanraj Sivalingam
 what would be your suggestion to capture the First Value of the "Assigned to" field(Task Object; Lookup Field)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're confirming the `Assigned To` value is changed constantly. So we can't use formula field for this kind of requests. Please create a simple `Record Triggered flow` as whenever the task created with `Assigned To` value,Our created flow fetch the first Queue/Owner name from the task and update it into `Sample` field *(field DataType: Text)*.

You're flow will need to be following structure.

- Run once after Task Created Only
- Decision Element (check the `Assigned to` ID is a Queue/User)
- Get Records Element(for each decision to fetch `Queue name` or `User's name`)
- Assignment Element (Assign the `Assigned to` value (user/queue name) into `Sample` field)
- Update Element (Update the Task record)

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great help

Comment: Additional question, how will you retrieve the first value of an existing record?

Comment: You can't get those values for existing record. Because until you're enable `Field History Tracking` for that `Assigned to` field, Salesforce can't track the changed values for existing records. so we can't get those values for existing records.